# DIV not showing after changing z-index

Tags: jquery, html, z-index, show, fadein

I'm busy with a "top of the week"-box which is displayed on some homepage.  A while ago an annoying little problem occured but my hope that it would just disappear, which sometimes happens, sunk to a low level.

See live example [HERE](http://nolybab.com/tiotw/).

Three sub items are shown on the left and after pageload every few seconds it will go to the next in the sequence (1->2, 2->3, 3->1). Initially item #1 is shown and item #2 + #3 are hidden and after click on thumb #2 -or- after a few seconds automatically, item #1 will disappear and item #2 will appear / slideIn / fadeIn / whatever...

Inside main item #1, #2 and #3 there is a **DIV1** with text content showing information about that item.

The styling is set to 50 transparency. Because the transparency is set to a lower-than-100 value, the text sometimes is difficult to read. To solve that... when user clicks on **DIV1** another **DIV2**, with a white background, is shown -behind- **DIV1**!

Now the text will be easier to read because the (combined) background transparency is lower.

**Works OK** directly after pageload (nav_to_slide2/3() not executed): click on **DIV1** will show **DIV2**.
**Works NOK** when nav_to_slide1/2/3() has been executed: click on **DIV1** will -not- show **DIV2**.

I guess this has something to do with z-index stuff, because *this* (or *some.parent*) was needed to change because of slide/fade effect?

I tried debugging but I can't find a fix. Note that alert =A=, =B= and =C= do always occur... even with NOK-case.

[Source JQUERY code](http://nolybab.com/tiotw/indexpage.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Keep it simple stupid" is very much in place here...
Found a solution (on stackoverflow) using css:

```
div.box_slide_over_text, div.box_slide_over_text:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; }

div.box_slide_over_text { opacity:0.45; filter:alpha(opacity=45); }
div.box_slide_over_text:hover { opacity:0.80; filter:alpha(opacity=80); }
```

Removed **DIV2** with corresponding z-index's entirely.
Check [live version](http://nolybab.com/tiotw/) for fixed version code.

Answer (score 1):

z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).
add `position:relative` to divs that use z-index.

Comment: I checked the code for your input... nothing found. Elements that will have z-index or where z-index will be changed are: #slide1, #slide2, #slide3; #slide1_over, #slide2_over, #slide3_over; resize_A_to, resize_B_to and resize_C_to <div class='box_slide abs nothidden rel' id='slide1' style=''><div class='box_slide_over rel' id='slide1_over' style='z-index:95;'><div class='box_slide_over_white abs hidden' id='resize_A_to' style='z-index:90;'> Class "abs" is "position:absolute;" and class "rel" is "position:relative;". So all is good right ?

Comment: If you're sure position rel and abs is the solution, please specify what jquery/css/html I need to change.
I just started manipulating div's and generally I'm more a table-person (lol), so maybe I miss something...